# Mockserver not responding running over https

Tags: java, apache, testing, https, mocking

My mockserver is running on a apache https connector over port 8443. But when I try to load the expectation using the following it does nothing. However when I use http connector it works like a charm.

```
new MockServerClient(ip, Integer.parseInt(port), contextPath)
                    .when(request, times, timeToLive)
                    .respond(response);
```

Based on my understanding it will use the http connector so I also tried

```
MockServerClient client = new MockServerClient(ip, Integer.parseInt(port), contextPath);
HttpForward httpForward = new HttpForward()
                            .withHost(ip)
                            .withPort(Integer.parseInt(port))
                            .withScheme(HttpForward.Scheme.HTTPS);

// when
ForwardChainExpectation forwardChainExpectation = client.when(request);
forwardChainExpectation.forward(httpForward);
```

What am I missing? 
Can the mock server work over a https connector?

Comment: I am using the mockserver war in apache.

Comment: Are you using that library? http://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/mockserver_clients.html#java-mockserver-client

Comment: yes. I am using this and the jar is mockserver-netty-3.10 for client.